# How to check value of a radio button coming in @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Is Java Fun?</title>
</head>
<body>
      <h1>Do you think Java is fun?</h1>
      
      <form action="/submitForm" method="POST">
      <input type="radio" name="RadioButton" value="Yes">Yes<br>
      <input type="radio" name="RadioButton" value="No">No<br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBox" value="check">Add to mailing list<br><br>
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" required><br>
      Email: <input type="text" name="email" required><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
</body>
</html>


**Controller.java**

package java.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
@GetMapping("/Form")
public String registerUser() {
    return "javaFun";
}

  @PostMapping("/submitForm")
  public String registerUser1( 
  
  @RequestParam String name,
  @RequestParam String email,
  @RequestParam (required=true) String RadioButton,
  @RequestParam (required=true)String CheckBox,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
  
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  
if(RadioButton=="Yes" && CheckBox=="check") {
    
  out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
        + "<html>\r\n"
        + "<head>\r\n"
        + "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\r\n"
        + "<title>Assignment 1</title>\r\n"
        + "</head>\r\n"
        + "<body>\r\n"
        + "    <h1>Thanks for filling out the form, " + name +"</h1>\r\n"
        + "    <h2>Glad you're having fun!</h2>\r\n"
        + "    <h2>We'll add your email: " + email +" to our list. </h2>\r\n"
        + "</body>\r\n"
        + "</html>");
}
 
else  if(RadioButton=="No" && CheckBox!="check")  {

      out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"
            + "<html>\r\n"
            + "<head>\r\n"
            + "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\r\n"
            + "<title>Assignment 1</title>\r\n"
            + "</head>\r\n"
            + "<body>\r\n"
            + "    <h1>Thanks for filling out the form, " + name +"</h1>\r\n"
            + "    <h2>Hope it gets better!</h2>\r\n"
            + "    <h2>We won't add your email to our list. </h2>\r\n"
            + "</body>\r\n"
            + "</html>");
}              
  return null; 
  }
 
  }
```

Hello this is my first Spring Starter project using Eclipse IDE. I have an issue with the getting and then checking the values of the radiobuttons.

This is want to see :

[image]

If I click 'yes' radiobutton, check the checkbox and fill the Textfileds , it is showing a blank webpage
after I hit submit.

or

If I click 'no' radiobutton, unchcheck the checkbox and fill the Textfileds , it is showing a blank webpage
after I hit submit.

[image: The two images are the two possible outcomes if I hit yes or no respectivel]

Comment: Use `equals` method to compare strings. Also your variables don't follow the standard naming conventions. Please follow [code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) for better readability.

Comment: Thanks Shashank Kadne. That was the only problem that was hindering my project.